# In Camel sending the query params as part of the main url as against sending query params via Exchange.HTTP_QUERY

Tags: apache-camel

In camel 2.16.1 I am sending a `HTTPS POST` request via Camel's `HTTP4` Component. The url looks like below:-

```
https4://debraj:debraj@example.com/oms-api/?Action=UpdateOrderInformation&ServiceName=OMS&Signature=25566099c0b6b6c5123bbfede4c91590512050668f957e2a43ef982a0dcf1c00&Timestamp=2016-04-14T12%3A44%3A17+0530&Version=1.0
```

The body looks something like below:-

```
{
  "Request": {
    "Orders": [
      {
        "id_sales_order": 397,
        "address_billing": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "phone": "1234567",
          "phone2": "1234",
          "address1": "Sesamestreet 123",
          "city": "Berlin",
          "postcode": "12345",
          "country": "Germany"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It is returning me:-

```
{
    "ErrorResponse": {
        "Head": {
            "RequestAction": "UpdateOrderInformation",
            "ErrorType": "Sender",
            "ErrorCode": "7",
            "ErrorMessage": "E007: Login failed. Signature mismatch"
        },
        "Body": ""
    }
}
```

If the same request is made by sending the query parameters under `Exchange.HTTP_QUERY` then it is giving me the correct response:-

```
headers.put(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, "Action=UpdateOrderInformation&ServiceName=OMS&Signature=25566099c0b6b6c5123bbfede4c91590512050668f957e2a43ef982a0dcf1c00&Timestamp=2016-04-14T12%3A44%3A17+0530&Version=1.0")

{
  "SuccessResponse": {
    "Head": {
      "RequestId": "",
      "RequestAction": "UpdateOrderInformation",
      "ResponseType": "",
      "Timestamp": "2015-07-02T12:26:03+0200"
    },
    "Body": []
}
```

Can someone please let me know:-

- Why the above two cases are behaving differently?
- Is it always recommended to send query parameters under `Exchange.HTTP_QUERY`? I am asking this because sending the query parameters with the main url is not failing always.

If something is not clear about my question please ask for it I will try to explain.

Comment: Maybe it's just copy/paste, but there's a double-quote at the end (but not the beginning) of the url at the top:  ...&Version=1.0"

Comment: Yeah it was because of the copy paste while framing the question. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your query parameters are changing every time i.e. your signature changes. Your signature sometimes could simply be having a + sign or SPACE in it (or characters like that) and then http4 converts the sign to %20 (or something else, depending on the character). You can inspect the signature the times that it fails, and determine if this is the case. I can't remember how I solved this issue in the past, but it seems like you have a solution already in hand. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I don't think that is the case signature is validated using the timestamp which is also send in the query params. If it is changing space or + sign , will it not do the same thing when the query params are sent via Exchange.HTTP_QUERY?

Comment: No this only happens in the URI. Exactly like when you go to http://goo gle.com which is converted to http://goo%20gle.com

Comment: The reason I felt that this might not be happening in this case is because I tried URL encoding the query params and then setting in the main URL. It was still failing but the same URL encoded query params was working fine when sent under Exchange.HTTP_QUERY.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the signature in RAW(signature) format in the URI and see what happens? http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html